# How to have column filtering on two headers for a grid/matrix/table (excel style)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Hell I am using ag-grid enterprise. I want to know what is the best way to to filter columns and rows:

eg:
col1 col2 col3
col1

col2

col3

When I filter out the column col2  with column selection I want the following result:

```
 col1 col3
```

col1

col3

So far I attempt to solve this with updating the rows based on external column filter (duplicating the state of what columns are currently viewed externally of ag-grid). But it is far from elegant, I wonder what would a better approach be?
Maybe it's a good use case for creating a custom plugin?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like what you want are RowGroups, and the toolpanel. See these two pages for details

[Row Grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/grouping/)
[Column Tool Panel](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/tool-panel-columns/)

Comment: No I want to have a a column and a corresponding row 
and be able tio hide both. Row groupiung is irrelevant in this case, please see the  described example and ask question if it is not clear to you.